# How to use strace to monitor files being saved on an smb share or being transferred over http

Tags: linux, strace

Can strace be used to trigger events or notify whenever a file is saved on an smb share or file is uploaded to a website over http/https?

Answer (score 0):

`strace` or `ltrace` will have difficulty tracing all traffic on a system, as they are designed to examine one program at a time. Also, it can be difficult to determine what type of traffic just on system calls.

Try network packet capture in general, and network intrusion detection systems in particular. Software like Snort is designed to identify conversations on the wire.